# splicing strings in two different way

Tags: python, string

```
import re , strings , os ,sys
sentence = "abcdefghijkl"
for i in range(0,len(sentence),3):
    twoletters = sentence[i:i+2] + sentence[i+1:i+3]
    print twoletters
```

this give me :

```
abbc
deef
ghhi
jkkl
```

where as i want:

```
ab
bc
cd
de
ef
fg
gh
hi
ij
jk
kl
```

How to do such splicing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> sentence = "abcdefghijkl"
>>> [sentence[i:i+2] for i in range(len(sentence) - 1)]
['ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'de', 'ef', 'fg', 'gh', 'hi', 'ij', 'jk', 'kl']
```

Answer (score 1):

Keeping in line with your thinking but simplifying, I would do the following

```
for i in range(0, len(sentence)-1):
    print sentence[i] + sentence[i + 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>>sentence = "abcdefghijkl"
>>>for i in range(0, len(sentence)-1):
>>>    print sentence[i:i+2]
ab
bc
cd
de
ef
fg
gh
hi
ij
jk
kl
```

Or use [List Comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/)

```
>>>[sentence[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(sentence)-1)]
['ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'de', 'ef', 'fg', 'gh', 'hi', 'ij', 'jk', 'kl']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from itertools import tee, izip, islice
>>> sentence = "abcdefghijkl"
>>> x, y = tee(sentence)
>>> y = islice(y, 1, None)
>>> for a,b in izip(x, y):
...     print a + "" + b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[sentence[i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(sentence)-1,1)]
```

['ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'de', 'ef', 'fg', 'gh', 'hi', 'ij', 'jk', 'kl']